# How to visualise and choose parameters spectrogram tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, data-science, tensorflow2.0

I have audio of 3 min duration ,I have  Waveform shape: (2880000,) so what should be the value for frame_length and frame_step

```
spectrogram = tf.signal.stft(waveform, frame_length=?, frame_step=?)

spectrogram = tf.abs(spectrogram)
```

On choosing frame_length=255 & frame_step=128 I get spectrogram shape as 22499,129 and when I try to visualise

```
def plot_spectrogram(spectrogram, ax):
  # Convert to frequencies to log scale and transpose so that the time is
  # represented in the x-axis (columns).
  log_spec = np.log(spectrogram.T)
  height = log_spec.shape[0]
  X = np.arange(2880000, step=height + 1)
  Y = range(height)
  ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, log_spec)


fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, figsize=(12, 8))
timescale = np.arange(audio.shape[0])
axes[0].plot(timescale, audio.numpy())
axes[0].set_title('Waveform')
axes[0].set_xlim([0, 2880000])
plot_spectrogram(spectrogram.numpy(), axes[1])
axes[1].set_title('Spectrogram')
plt.show()
```

I get this error  `Dimensions of C (129, 22499) are incompatible with X (22154) and/or Y (129); see help(pcolormesh)`

So question is how to choose parameters and then visualise

Comment: tensoeflow guide says watch this  https://www.coursera.org/lecture/audio-signal-processing/stft-2-tjEQe but I cant understand this

Comment: why no one answer